# Display negative exponents always as fraction

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I want *Mathematica* to display negative exponents always as fractions. I already tried:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
(* Notation[1/a_^b_ <==> a_^-b_] *)
Notation[
  ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"1", "/", RowBox[{"a_", "^", "b_"}]}]]
  ⟺ 
  ParsedBoxWrapper[RowBox[{"a_", "^", RowBox[{"-", "b_"}]}]]]
```

While I do have

```
x^-z
```

> ```
> 1/x^z
> ```

the following doesn't work:

```
x^-(2z)
```

> ```
> x^-2z
> ```

Some hints ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Thank you @Sektor for reformatting !

Comment: You are welcome ! If you are still experiencing troubles in the future, please, refer to the help centre for code formatting practices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for my case. It still uses the Notation Package and makes use of PatternWrappers:

Here is the Code:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
(*Notation[1/Simplify[a_^(-b_ c_)] <==> a_^TemplateBox[b_?Negative] c_]*)
(*Notation[(a_^d_)/Simplify[a_^(-b_ c_)] <==> a_^TemplateBox[b_?Negative] c_+d_]*)
ClearNotations[]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
FractionBox["1", 
SuperscriptBox["", 
TemplateBox[{
RowBox[{"Simplify", "[", 
SuperscriptBox["a_", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "b_"}], " ", "c_"}]], "]"}]}, 
  "NotationPatternTag"]]]] \[DoubleLongLeftArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
SuperscriptBox["a_", 
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{
RowBox[{"b_", "?", "Negative"}]}, "NotationPatternTag"], " ", "c_"}]]]]
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox["a_", "d_"], 
TemplateBox[{
RowBox[{"Simplify", "[", 
SuperscriptBox["a_", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "b_"}], " ", "c_"}]], "]"}]}, 
  "NotationPatternTag"]]] \[DoubleLongLeftArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[

SuperscriptBox["a_", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{
RowBox[{"b_", "?", "Negative"}]}, "NotationPatternTag"], " ", "c_"}], 
   "+", "d_"}]]]]
```