# Replacement rule to display negative exponents as denominators

Tags: pattern-matching, output-formatting, replacement, formatting

Suppose I have an expression of the form:

```
expr=f[t]^b + f[t]^a g[t]^-a + g[t]^-c
```

And I want to create a rule to convert negative exponents to denominators.  In the above example, this could be achieved manually as follows:

```
expr /. f[t]^a* g[t]^-a -> (f[t]/g[t])^a
```

> $\left(\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}\right)^a+f(t)^b+g(t)^{-c}$

How would I achieve this with a general pattern match, independent of the identities of the bases and the exponents?  In pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```
expr /. [some expression]^x*[some other expression]^-x -> 
  (some expression/some other expression)^x
```

I've made several attempts, without success.

Thus far, the only question I've been able to find on the subject is this, but the OP didn't specifically request a simple pattern-match replacement rule. Perhaps as a consequence, the answer is much more complicated than I'd like:

[Display negative exponents always as fraction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47643/display-negative-exponents-always-as-fraction)

Here's a related question, which seeks to do the opposite:

[How is it possible to prevent separation of negative and positive exponents when symbolic simplifying?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166800/how-is-it-possible-to-prevent-separation-of-negative-and-positive-exponents-when)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr /. c_. p_^e_  q_^(-1 e_) :> c (p/q)^e // TeXForm
```

> $\left(\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}\right)^a+f(t)^b+g(t)^{-c}$

Comment: Yup, that's it—thanks!  Since your first version, w/o the `c_.` , worked fine, I assume you added it to make it more canonical.  If so, when would the absence of  the `c_.` cause a failure?  I'd be happy to accept the answer but, respecting site conventions, I'll wait the usual couple of days.

Comment: @theorist, added `c_.` to cover cases like  `expr2 = f[t]^b + someCoeff f[t]^a g[t]^-a + g[t]^-c`